# How to index a table in Postgres to speed up ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

How do you create an index in PostgreSQL 11 to speed up a specific query containing an `ORDER BY`?

I have a query that needs to get the first 100 records from a table containing 2M records, along with a few common filters like:

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name
FROM users
WHERE active = true AND region IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY last_active_timestamp DESC;
```

Without the `ORDER BY` clause, it returns in ~1 sec, almost instantly. However, with the clause, it takes an excruciating ~5 minutes.

So I tried creating a partial index like:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY my_user_index ON users (active, region, last_active_timestamp DESC NULLS LAST)
WHERE region IN (1, 2, 3) AND active = True;
```

but that had virtually no effect. The above query still takes several minutes. Is that just a limitation of `ORDER BY` in Postgres, or is there a different type of index I could use to speed it up?

Comment: Could you include an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Try to create the index with only `last_active_timestamp` column on index. The `region` and `active` maintain on `where` clause

Comment: Have you tried a simpler index that pertains only to the ORDER BY clause? something like `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY my_user_index ON users (last_active_timestamp DESC NULLS LAST)`.

Comment: Where's "*the first 100*" in your query?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an index with the `ORDER BY` in your query, you need to index on all the relevant columns (last_active_timestamp, along with a condition to include only active==true and regions a,b,c). This will essentially pull the data out in order for you).

Also, if you share your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, you may see a `Sort Method: external merge Disk: ####kB`, indicating that the sort spilled out to disk and not in memory, due to an insufficiently-sized `work_mem`.  The solution would then be to increase `work_mem` to a value of at least `####kB`, and try again.

Note that you can set `work_mem` on a per-session basis, as a global change in `work_mem` could potentially have negative side-effects, such as running out of memory, because `postgresql.conf`-configured `work_mem` is allocated for each session (basically, it has a multiplicative effect).

If the query is still slow after tuning up `work_mem` (i.e., it's all sorting in memory, and it's still slow), then your returned data set is simply too large to sort quickly.

Comment: Ordering might be obtained from an index since they are ordered (at least standard btrees are). But the used columns did avoid using the index.

Answer (score 1):

To try an index was correct but you used the wrong one. Try this here:

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY my_user_index
    ON users (last_active_timestamp DESC)
    WHERE region IN (1, 2, 3)
        AND active = true;
```

Your index was only sorted by `last_active_timestamp` after already being sorted by `active` and `region`, thus you could not just use the index to have your sorted output.

For some more speedup, you could also include the columns of your select-clause within the index using `INCLUDE (id, first_name, last_name)`. Now your query can (if the planner chooses so and I think it will) run on the index only without touching the table data at all.